# Can the character Ziggy Stardust survive in the vacuum of space?

Tags: rock-music

The famous David Bowie character, Ziggy Stardust, is a "spaceman" from Mars. Over the course of his multi-album story, he comes to earth, rocks out, is worshipped, and dies. After recently re-listening to the songs, I started to wonder about the in-universe environment of Mars and how Ziggy reached the Earth.

My question is: **Can the character Ziggy Stardust survive in the vacuum of space?**

Does something about his biology (or perhaps inbuilt technology) allow him to survive in this environment where humans would die?

Ziggy Stardust's Wiki articles—both on Wikipedia and on the David Bowie wiki—make no mention of this (nor his means for reaching Earth, which could have provided clues to answer this question). I couldn't personally pick out anything that could answer this while listening to the music.

I'm looking for citations from the lyrics, from events or set pieces made in Bowie's live performances, or behind-the-scenes statements from Bowie or the band.
Failing any of that, promotional materials could also suffice.

[image]

Comment: We see him on Mars, so at the very least he can survive on a world with an atmosphere over a hundred times thinner that Earth's

Comment: *Ziggy is advised in a dream by the infinites to write the coming of a starman, so he writes “Starman,” which is the first news of hope that the people have heard. So they latch onto it immediately. The starmen that he is talking about are called the infinites, and they are black-hole jumpers .... They arrive somewhere in Greenwich Village. They don’t have a care in the world and are of no possible use to us. They just happened to stumble into our universe by black-hole jumping. Their whole life is traveling from universe to universe.*

Comment: David Bowie is the reason drugs are so expensive, because he took them all and there's none left for anyone else. - https://www.rollingstone.com/feature/beat-godfather-meets-glitter-mainman-william-burroughs-interviews-david-bowie-92508/

Comment: "*Bowie: I used Mars merely as a common denominator meaning anything that was out of our own particular area of what is termed cosmic perception. Like anything from another planet - or another source of life - or any other kind of life. I narrowed it down and made it a comic cartoon kind of thing and made it Mars. Why not Mars? It probably won't come from Mars but Mars is something that everyone can identify with.* - http://www.5years.com/radint74.htm

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nXWLu_DsvCE - Ziggy's genesis (and demise)

Comment: @Valorum is that last comment your way of telling me I'm looking too deeply into this (author-described as—) one-dimensional character? 

Comment: Bowie certainly isn't consistent in his description of this character or their traits. He's either a human from Earth, a human from Mars, an alien from Mars or an alien not from Mars but from elsewhere that spent time on Mars